# Eclipse PDT Flags "Errors" in Comment Blocks

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Not a big deal, I can ignore it, but it's annoying.

Using: Eclipse Photon 2018-06. PHP 5.6. CentOS 7.

There are thousands of lines of code, often with formatted comment blocks before function definitions. E.g.:

```
1 /**
2  * MyKoolFunction
3  * Does Kool Things
4  * @param arr $input_array
5  */
6 public function MyKoolFunction($input_array=array()) {
etc.
```

Then Eclipse flags an error at the line 4, that:

`arr cannot be resolved to a type`

THIS IS ONLY A COMMENT. The original author used "arr" instead of "array". Who cares whether it can be resolved to a type? There's no issue with the web server, which properly ignores comments. Everybody (except Eclipse) will read it and understand the meaning.

There are dozens of permutations of this all over the place, "unknown", dollar signs left off, misspelled types, even types left out -- then it flags the word after the variable. E.g.:

```
 * @param $name the name of the client
```

Flags "the".

I know it's probably doing this for some automatic documentation tool, but I don't care about such.

Is there a way to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable type validation in PDT, go to preferences -> PHP -> Validation -> Errors/Warning

You can't disable PHPDoc validation only.

1. PHPDoc isn't simple comment, it by design instruct IDE how to interpret code
2. Because you have "arr" rather than array, during code assist PDT will search arr class, so you might si invalid Code Assist.

Comment: Yah, I'm switching to NetBeans.